# JQuery $.post() response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I have a problem with response of $.post call.

I would insert in a table data with angular. The date are response of php call. I call php with:

```
function AppCtrl($scope){
   $scope.seeTable = function(){
     $.post("/testJson.php", function(json){
       //setResponse(json); 
         $scope.contacts = json;
     });
   $scope.seeThisTable = !$scope.seeThisTable;
};
//Not working
function setResponse(json){
  $scope.contacts = json;
}
```

Then I insert in the table:

```
 <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
   <td> {{contact.name}} </td>
   <td> {{contact.phone}} </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

My php is:

```
<?php
$array = array(
            0 => array('name' => 'Peter',
                       'phone' => '555-5552'),
            1 => array('name' => 'Jhon',
                       'phone' => '555-1235'),
            2 => array('name' => 'Ron',
                       'phone' => '555-5122'),
            3 => array('name' => 'Harry',
                       'phone' => '555-5514')
         );

echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

But $scope.contacts are empty. The problem are extract the response of $.post() but when i try to get out json to function $.post() are ever empty. I try with call another function and pass json inside but not working, inside the function setResponse the json are correctly but don't set $scope.contacts, after the end of function $scope.contacts are empty.

There is any way to extract response?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create plunkr for this?

Comment: does  json variable has any data ?

Comment: you can try success function for post method  it wil be called only after data comes from post then you can assigne $scope.contacts= result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular `$http` sevice like this..

```
function AppCtrl($scope,$http){
   $scope.seeTable = function(){
    $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/testJson.php'
        }).then(function  success(data,status,xhr){
            $scope.contacts = data.data;
            //console.log(data);
        },
        function error(data,status,xhr){
            alert(data.status);
        }
        }); 
}
```

AND HTML part

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
   <td> {{contact['name']}} </td>
   <td> {{contact['phone']}} </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are leaving angular's scope when calling $.post. That is JQuery.

Solutions:

1) use the $http service that angular provides

2) you can call this in the post response method.

```
$timeout(function () {
   $scope.contacts = json
});
```

or you can call $scope.$apply